# Grails Many to Many Association Querying

Tags: grails, associations, querying

I have a many to many relationship.

```
class Post {
    String title
    static hasMany = [tags:Tag]
}

class Tag {
    static hasMany = [posts:Post]
}
```

I would like to get a list of posts for a tag that have some other criteria (like a sort order, partial title match, etc). Do I *have* to use the grails criteria to achieve this? Or is there some way to do something like this:

```
Post.findAllByTitleLikeAndTagsContains("partial title", aTag)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think dynamic finders will allow you to get into one to many or many to many associations - you have to do a criteria or go the HQL query route.   You can only query by one to one association, not by one to many.  (see section [5.4.1 Dynamic Finders](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html))

Comment: Yep, dynamic finders only support simple properties - criteria time!

Comment: That's what I thought. I really wish grails had an easy way to do this, but I guess I'll just have to put it in JIRA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use withCriteria,for example:

```
Post.withCriteria{
    tags {
        eq 'id',aTag.id
    }
 }
```

Comment: True, but if you read my question you would have noticed that I was asking for a way to do it without using criteria.